# Word for rewriting a sentence so it won't be misunderstood?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for rewriting a sentence so it won't be <s>understood incorrectly</s> misunderstood

For example:

"I went to Washington to go to <s>The</s> the White House and then <s>return</s> returned."

In this sentence I meant to return from The White House, but somebody thought that I meant to return from Washington, so in order to avoid confusion, I changed it to "and then return‌**ed** from The White House" and told him I'll rewrite the sentence.

Is there any word that means rewriting the sentence so it won't be misunderstood? Is saying I'll "rewrite the sentence" correct?

Comment: Saying "rewrite the sentence" is perfectly fine. You can also say "I'll revise it," or "I'll rephrase it" too.

Comment: By the way, welcome to ELL!

Comment: Do you even have to include "and then return"? It would be very odd to go to the White House and not return. Also, I mis-read your question (twice!) as "understood correctly" - as "understood incorrectly" is unusual. You could consider "misundertood" instead.

Comment: @toandfro English can be so difficult sometimes, thank you for alerting me - this sentence is only an example that crossed my mind.

Comment: @almousawi I agree with toandfro that you don't **need** *then returned* here. It's not technically incorrect to included it, but it is **redundant**. Unless you're using a word or phrase as a *rhetorical device* (i.e. for effect/emphasis), you should remove redundancies from your writing. That's the only revision necessary to remove the ambiguity (or, as Tyler James Young says directly below, to disambiguate your sentence). I don't have enough room here to explain, so I'll add an answer. But the answers you've got are pretty solid, so +1 to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, it's sufficient to say that your writing needs to be *edited*, or that you need to *edit* it; but, as jwpat7 and DamkerngT. suggest, it's standard to say *revise, rewrite, rephrase, amend,* or *clarify*, to give you some additional examples.

*Edit, revise, rewrite,* and *rephrase* all mean to change the phrasing. So too do *clarify* and *amend*, but clarification, like amendment, suggests you're adding additional text to make your meaning more clear. You can *amend* or *clarify* your text without actually changing the original phrasing though. A clarification and an amendment or addendum, as  their names suggest, are additional text

> I [*am editing*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/editing)
>   my answer because it is
>   [*ambiguous*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/ambiguous).
>
> He thinks I should revise/rephrase this sentence so that its meaning
>   can't be
>   [*misconstrued*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/misconstrue)/misinterpreted.
>
> She [*amended*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amend) her
>   answer to
>   [clarify](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/clarify) it's
>   meaning.

I think that *disambiguate* is a great word in that it's highly specific, but it's the least natural choice to me. I've seen lists of *disambiguations*, like in Wikipedia for example, but I've rarely heard it used by speakers (i.e. it's such a specific and technical term, that it has limited applications; the average person wouldn't use it regularly).

It's a good answer in that it **does** mean exactly what you mean to say; it's just an uncommon word.

And as for the comment on redundancy I made under your OP, when you talk about **traveling to** a place, and particularly a place that is not a residence--i.e., residence in the sense of an ordinary home or an inn; the White House is indeed a residence, but few are permitted to stay there overnight--**traveling** back **from** is always **implied**.

In most cases, it's best to avoid using words or phrases that are redundant, which neither convey nor connote any additional meaning. There are times where you might want to use redundancy as a rhetorical device for emphasis, but this is not one.

> "I went to Washington to go to The White House. <del>and then
>   <del>return</del> returned.</del>"

I understand your intention, and your edit does improve the grammar; but this revision actually introduces more uncertainty, which is the opposite of which you'd hoped to achieve.

Here's why:

As I've said, the return from the White House is already implied, and is, in fact, the expected result. That's why it's unnecessary.

When you say, *I went to Washington, D.C. to go to [*-or- *to see*] <del>The</del> the White House,* your statement is very clear and concise.

***Side note***: If you really want to signal that you've **both** traveled and returned, you can say ***I/I've just got/gotten back from DC; I went to see the White House.***

And by the way, [definite] articles are only capitalized when they are the 1st word of a title, which *the White House* is not; it's a proper noun, so the article shouldn't be capitalized.

When you add *and then returned*, not only is it unnecessary--no one would assume that you had either taken up residence at the White House or that you'd stayed overnight--it's not clear where you're returning from. Did you return from D.C. or just from the White House, or both? Are you back home now or are you still in the District of Columbia?

So how would you know whether to include or to exclude this information?

When I said that this is sometimes done for effect, I meant that you may **want to emphasize** that you made more that one trip back-and-forth for several reasons.

For example, let's assume that at least one, and possibly more, of the following aspects apply: that you live far way or that there was heavy traffic/long travel times involved, that you didn't accomplish what you'd set out to accomplish, that your trip was poorly thought out, or that some part of this trip was pointless, stressful, a waste of time, etc. The following paragraph is extremely redundant, but, if you're writing a narrative, it strengthens it.

> I drove **all the way** to Washington, D.C. on a whim, ***just to see the White
>   House***, but when **I'd finally gotten there** it was
>   **closed that day** for renovations, **forcing me to rent a hotel
>   room.** When **I'd gone back the next day**, the lines were **so long**,
>   that **I ended up spending the *entire* second day in line**;
>   **the damn place closed long before I'd even gotten close** to the entrance, so **back again to my hotel I drove.** On my **third try**,
>   I **finally, after days of hassle, did make it inside, but not before wasting several days** trying. Next time, **I'll know to plan ahead so that I don't waste
>   so much time, money, and gas** driving **back-and-forth**.

Comment: Thank you Mr.John, your answer is indeed more than sufficient :), I didn't know that disambiguate was uncommon! BTW, you said 'spending the entire second day in line' shouldn't it be 'in a line'?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't **have to be** *in a line*. First, it's a shortened form of *spending the entire 2nd day **waiting** in line* or ***queued** in line*. And second, in the US, *standing in line* is idiomatic. So while it's **not incorrect** to include the indefinite article, it's not required. As for *disambiguate*, I've never heard it **spoken** in my entire life. A writer wouldn't typically say *I need to disambiguate this sentence*. With that said, **I up-voted that answer because it does mean *precisely* what you asked**, to the letter.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [“disambiguate”](https://www.google.com/search?q=disambiguate):

> **dis·am·big·u·ate**
> *disamˈbigyo͞oˌāt*
>   *<sup>verb</sup>*
>   1.
>   remove uncertainty of meaning from (an ambiguous sentence, phrase, or other linguistic unit).

Comment: Thank you! BTW, is "and then return" correct?

Comment: @almousawi, while it is grammatically valid, it adds no value to the sentence; talking about the trip in the past tense implies that you have already returned anyway.

Answer (score 3):

“I'll rewrite the sentence” is a correct phrasing, as are too  “I’ll revise it” and “I’ll rephrase it”, which Damkerng mentioned.  Also consider  “I’ll revise for clarity” and  “I’ll remove the ambiguity”.

Note, you should remove the definite article in  “I went to the Washington” if you mean you went to Washington DC.  You might say “I went to the Washington” if you went to a hotel, building, or event which is named Washington and are referring to it.